# Is it possible for sidebar to start after div on html page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position, sidebar

I want to know if it's possible for sidebar to be static until i reach it through scrolling on the page? 
I want it to be positioned after Jumbotron and then stick to the left and top when scrolling down. Not being on top of everything like now, z-index, margin, offset doesn't work apparently...

I would like to know if is it even possible.

Here's all code, doesn't work until you pop it on your IDE like gitpod etc. Just copy please.
[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/n4Bsll2ocF)

Only HTML down here /

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Titul </title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-xm-row fixed-top nav-custom">
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" id="about" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" id="experience" href="#">Smth</a>
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" id="contact" href="#">Number 3</a>
            <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" id="cv" href="#">Number 4</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="about">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-about">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="assets/images/avatr.jpg" class="avatar img-fluid" alt="Profile Picture">
                <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3 hidden">
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-9 order-10">
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a sidebar, can you be more clear, please

Comment: On page where i posted all code css doesn't load idk why, and it didn't show any side bar... I don't know how to attach it so it's visible, that's why i asked to please copy and paste it on any IDE, should be seen then

Comment: You can only do that using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just use scrollspy

use:
`<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">`

here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/michaelgermini/pen/XNagZR?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's exactly what i wanted, except section updating, so i'll just get rid of that, thanks a lot, have a great day!